# Synthesize of "REAL VARIABLES" in Vivado 2020.1

Tags: vhdl, vivado, floating-point

I am using the following libraries:

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
library ieee_proposed;
use ieee_proposed.fixed_pkg.all;
use ieee_proposed.fixed_float_types.all;

I cannot synthesize real variables such as the following operations:

```
signal r,s : real range  0.0 to 15.0;  
begin 

    s <= r * 0.5;
```

Is there any way Vivado can synthesize this?
Thanks.

*UPDATE:* Thank for all the responses! I am procceding with fixed point numbers to be able to synthesize the code.

Comment: Check the library paths match where it was saved

Comment: Hello! I found the library and I still looking for where I should save it in the project. Could you let me know? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have your setup. Check your setup under File , edit or other headers

Comment: Synthesisers can synthesise simple arithmetic on whole numbers, but if you want to run-time process real numbers, you have to implement fixed/floating point unit algorithms. Simple `s <= r * 0.5` won't work. Even multiplication operator is not synthesisable always (depends on FPGA part, multiplier...).

Comment: With a minimal, complete, and verifiable example one or more of your readers might recommend a solution using either ieee_proposed.fixed_pkg or ieee_proposed.float_pkg which would be synthesis eligible using types representing binary values.

Answer (score 1):

To determine whether a given construct is synthesisable in Vivado, you can refer to the [Vivado Design Suite User Guide: Synthesis (UG901)](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug901-vivado-synthesis/VHDL-Constructs-Support-Status) document. This includes a full breakdown of which Verilog, SystemVerilog, and VHDL constructs are supported by the synthesis tools.

If we refer to the VHDL constructs (link above), we find:

[image: Partial list of supported constructs]

So `REAL` constructs are only supported when calculating the value for constants - basically anything for which the result can be determined at the time of synthesis.

In your case you are trying to calculate a non-constant value, one which depends on the value of a signal not known at synthesis time (i.e. a variable). This is therefore not supported.

Answer (score 0):

The closest that can be done is to use fixed point numbers.

VHDL has support for a fixed point data type which keeps track of where the decimal point is for fixed point numbers.

http://math.unife.it/ing/informazione/Linguaggi-hw/lucidi-delle-lezioni/lucidi-anni-precedenti-al-2019-2020/aritmetica-fixed-e-floating-point-in-vhdl